Debian11 network interfaces renaming issues
We have been on Debian 10 and we operate with "net.ifnames=0" kernel parameter to keep the network interfaces named 'eth0', 'eth1', etc. because of requirements of a legacy software license which cares about the name and MAC address.
We had an issue in VMware where the network interfaces would coming up out of the order after adding a third interface, so we created a UDEV rules file "/etc/udev/rules.d/76-persistent-net.rules" to fix this.
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="00:01:02:03:04:5a", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="00:01:02:03:04:5b", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="00:01:02:03:04:5c", NAME="eth2"

All was fine until our attempts to in-place upgrade to Debian 11.  Since then, we can't get all the interfaces to come up. Only one interface will come up as eth0 (but the wrong one). dmesg output does not show any 'rename' messages, and I do see the eth interfaces listed with the name and MAC which are not what we want.
[   6.679702] e1000 0000:02:00.0 eth0: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:01:02:03:04:5b
[   7.043036] e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth1: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:01:02:03:04:5a
[   7.415488] e1000 0000:02:02.0 eth2: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:01:02:03:04:5c

We did remove the "net.ifnames=0" kernel parameter and ensured the names were going back to the "ensX" values, and converted to using the systemd method of '/etc/systemd/network/10-[eth#].link' with the match/name as outlined in this article, but it didn't help and we get the same result.
Looking for ideas... Thank you!
*** UPDATE ***
Thank you to @JaromandaX for the comment... So 'systemd-networkd.service' was not enabled.  I commented out the UDEV rules, put the 10-ethX.link files in place,  enabled 'systemd-networkd.service', and verified with is-enabled... However no change from what was happening with UDEV.
I do see now in the journal log:
systemd-udevd[331]: eth0: Failed to rename network interface 2 from 'eth0' to 'eth1': File exists

This makes me think that the network interfaces are still trying to use the 'ethX' names even though I don't have the "net.ifnames=0" kernel parameter set...  But if I remove the systemd 10-ethX.link files and the UDEV rules, I end up with interfaces named 'ensX'...
This is very confusing as to what is going on.

converted to using the systemd method is systemd-networkd.service enabled

Thank you, it wasn't enabled but this didn't help.  I'll post the detail into the question.
